# Vue prototype MyModule and set scope to Vue

Tags: ecmascript-6, vue.js, es6-modules

When I extend Vue by

```
import api from '@/js/api'
Vue.prototype.$api = api
```

In my api I can access the Vue instance through `this` if I `default export`the function

```
//api.js
import Vue from 'vue'

export default function () {
   console.log('default export', this)
   //=> Vue
}
```

I would have to call this function by `Vue.prototype.$api()`

Now I would like to expand my api.js to contain multiple functions and private vars without loosing `this` as a reference to the vue instance like when I use the axios library.

I would like to be able to export a module without loosing the `this` context.

```
var MyModule = {
    this.fn1 = function(){console.log(this) //=>Vue}
    this.fn1 = function(){console.log(this) //=>Vue}
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You should avoid writing code like that.

Comment: in Axios I can do `this.$http.get('xxx').then( //this=>vue')` which is extremely convenient in Vue. I would like to have that at my api also.

Comment: This can hardly be recommended. Relying on dynamic `this` is evil and results in crappy ES6 OOP code. Using existing variable as a namespace worked for jQuery, but in modular environment there's no excuse for that. if you need `api`, import it.

Answer (score 0):

I turns out this is not possible.

The `this` context in `.then()` is set through the arrow function.